# Event horizon as a Null hypersurface

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, event-horizon

I have two questions regarding the Event horizon as a null hypersurface.

1. I know that for a null hypersurface, the normal vector to the surface is null (zero-length). It means normal to the event horizon is also null, as EH is a null hypersurface. But why is the normal to the event horizon  null? Is it because light can not escape from the event horizon, that's why the normal is null(means of zero magnitudes)? Exactly why is the normal to the event horizon  null?
2. My second question is , why is the normal to a null hypersurface  also tangent to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As can be seen in the illustration, the EH is where the light-cone tilts just so all of the timelike geodesics go inside the EH. This means that the some null direction is tangent to both the light-cone and the EH.
2. A null vector is perpendicular to itself, as $n^\mu n_\mu =0$

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I understand the second answer. But I am not able to understand the first one. Can you give some references for this?

Comment: @anamika You can refer to Eric Poisson's book on Relativist's toolkit where he discusses hypersurfaces.